# writing http response in case of CTRL-C interrupt

Tags: api, go, http, response

I have a go application which process http requests. At some point, I might have many requests being processed, and I press ctrl-c ( maybe because database server is down ).

I want to give "internal error" response to all requests which have not been processed yet.

It's unclear to me how to access http.ResponseWriter of unprocessed requests after capturing ctrl-c signal.

Comment: It sounds like you are approaching this incorrectly. Why would you have a web application deployed where it runs in a terminal in the first place? Normally you would have the application automatically return a reasonable error when the database server is down, rather than trying to handle a SIGINT to signal pending requests.

Comment: It's an api service which get hit by some external clients. I want them to know that their request couldn't be processed because of some internal error. I just can't close my application without giving them some response in case of interrupt. sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: You're never going to be able to get 100% of all requests, some may come in during shutdown, and others may have starting writing responses. If that's acceptable, then basically all handlers need to look for a shutdown notification. If the specific error isn't important, then use [`Shutdown`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server.Shutdown).

Comment: It's probably good to use "Graceful Shutdown".

Comment: I found this article helpful in the past, https://medium.com/honestbee-tw-engineer/gracefully-shutdown-in-go-http-server-5f5e6b83da5a, 'Graceful shutdown in Go http server'.